# how to compare values in two columns of two different tables using cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cursor

```
declare
    v_column varchar2(100);
    v_incident_id number;
    v_check_incident  varchar2(100);
    v_check_audit varchar2(100);
    query_str varchar2(1000);
    cursor c1 is
        select COLUMN_NAME 
        from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
        where upper(TABLE_NAME)=upper('Incidents');
begin
    open c1;
    loop
        fetch c1 into v_column;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        select incident_id into v_incident_id from incident_audit;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('incident column: '||v_column);
        select v_column 
        into v_check_incident 
        from incidents 
        where incident_id= v_incident_id;   
        select  to_char(v_column) 
        into v_check_audit  
        from incident_audit  
        where incident_id=v_incident_id; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('incident column: '||v_check_incident);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('audit column : '||v_check_audit);
        if(v_check_incident != v_check_audit)
        then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('inside insert');
            insert into PHIIT_AUD(AUDIT_ID ,INCIDENT_ID,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_ON,COLUMN_NAME)
            values(audit_id_seq.nextval,v_incident_id,v_check_audit,v_check_incident,NVL(v('APP_USER'),USER),sysdate,v_column);
        end if;
    end loop;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total number of rows : '||c1%ROWCOUNT);
    close c1;
end;
```

Problem: Getting Column names from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS in cursor and using it to compare with the other column of other table

```
output : incident column: INCIDENT_ID
incident column: INCIDENT_ID
audit column : INCIDENT_ID
incident column: BUSINESS_UNIT_ID
incident column: BUSINESS_UNIT_ID
audit column : BUSINESS_UNIT_ID
```

The cursor is returning value as column_name instead of its value in order to compare.

Answer (score 2):

> "The cursor is returning value as column_name "

Of course it is, that's what you're telling it to do.  `select v_column from incidents` means select the value in the variable.

What you need to do is use *Dynamic SQL* to create a select statement which substitutes the value in the  variable for a column name:  `'select '||v_column||' from incidents'` .

Here is the sort of thing you need to do.

```
declare
    v_column varchar2(100);
    v_incident_id number;
    v_check_incident  varchar2(100);
    v_check_audit varchar2(100);
    query_str varchar2(1000);
    cursor c1 is
        select COLUMN_NAME 
        from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
        where upper(TABLE_NAME)=upper('Incidents');
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open c1;
    loop
        fetch c1 into v_column;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        select incident_id into v_incident_id from incident_audit;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('incident column: '||v_column);
        --  dynamic SQL
        open rc for 
            'select'|| v_column ||
             ' from incidents where incident_id= :1'
             using v_incident_id;   
        fetch rc into v_check_incident;
        close rc;
        open rc for 
            'select'|| v_column ||
             ' from incident_audit   where incident_id= :1'
             using v_incident_id;   
        fetch rc into v_check_audit;
        close rc;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('incident column: '||v_check_incident);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('audit column : '||v_check_audit);
        if(v_check_incident != v_check_audit)
        then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('inside insert');
            insert into PHIIT_AUD(AUDIT_ID ,INCIDENT_ID,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_ON,COLUMN_NAME)
            values(audit_id_seq.nextval,v_incident_id,v_check_audit,v_check_incident,NVL(v('APP_USER'),USER),sysdate,v_column);
        end if;
    end loop;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total number of rows : '||c1%ROWCOUNT);
    close c1;
end;
```

I have kept it close to your original implementation so you can understand the principle.  However, I think this is a poor implementation which will be very inefficient if you have lots of audits to verify.  But addressing that is a different matter.

Comment: FWIW, I especially agree with your last paragraph. I didn't go depth into the code, so I may be wrong, but couldn't this be solved at relational level ? Maybe _that_ would be the right question to ask for the OP...

Comment: It says -> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement